# Web App occassionally returns wrong data set under moderate to heavy load. How do I fix?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a web app with a hand-written DAL. It uses Microsoft Application Blocks to actually connect to a MS SQL server database.

When the application is under moderate to heavy load it will return a wrong result set. There is no systematic way to reproduce the error. I can rerun the query in SQL Server Management Studio and get the correct results every time.

I get an error's like the following

```
DataBinding: 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' does not contain a property 
    with the name 'TitleName'.
```

and

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: TitleId at 
    System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName)
```

Comment: I just wanted to add the question, because we couldn't find anything that referred to this as a possible cause. It's common knowledge that static strings are bad, but trying to diagnose one is tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue ended up being an AJAX call to a method that used a **static** SqlConnection object.

This object would be in the connection pool, and would be reassigned to something else and would mutate. So if User A is loading the page when the AJAX method was called and User B is Requesting a page and get's User A's Static connection calamity occurs.